# draw a line on ArcGIS map fro iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, arcgis, esri, esri-arc-engine

I am now moving to `ArcGIS` maps for one of my iOS project.

how do you draw a line between two points. in the case of `MapKit` you use `MKPolyLine`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps to this if you don't have any map layers defined yet.  The classes you'll need are [documented here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-ios-sdk/apiref/annotated.html).  Your map view (`AGSMapView`) needs to have a graphics layer (`AGSGraphicsLayer`).  You can add `AGSGeometry` objects to the graphics layer, such as a `AGSSimpleLineGeomtry`.  You set the geometry of the `AGSSimpleLineGeometry` object from the `AGSPolyline` object which defines its geometry. Something like this:

1. Use the [`AGSPolyline`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-ios-sdk/apiref/interface_a_g_s_polyline.html) class to define the geometry (`AGSPolyline` is a subclass of `AGSGeometry`).
2. Create an `AGSGraphic` object and set its geometry property to the polyline geometry created first. Use you can use one of the subclasses of `AGSGraphic` such as `AGSSimpleLineGeometry`.
3. Add the `AGSGraphic` object to an `AGSGraphicsLayer`, which has been added to your map (`AGSMapView` is a `UIView` subclass)